# Django form field validation error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to validate if form field is None when user submits the form and raise a ValidationError exception:

```
def clean_street_number(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['street_number'] is None:
        raise ValidationError(
            ('You forgot to write your street number')
        )
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['street_number']
```

When I fill the form and submit without street number, Django crashes with message:

```
The view core.decorators.add_location didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

**views.py**

```
def add_property_location(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            p = form.save(commit=False)
            p.user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
            p.save()
            return redirect('add_description')

    else:
        form = LocationForm()
        return render(request, 'add_location.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: When creating the corresponding field in your form, have you given the default paramater `blank=True`?

Comment: Yes, the field has blank=True, null=True

Comment: The error message clearly shows the problem is in the view. You should post the code of that view, not an unrelated form method.

Comment: try doing this code: `if len(self.cleaned_data['street_number']) < 1`

Comment: Form doesn't seem to be the problem, please post your view

Comment: I've updated the question with my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, your view is not returning a response for post requests when the form is invalid.

You can fix this by moving the final return statement out of the if block. This way, the view will render the template and show the invalid form and its errors.

```
else:
    form = LocationForm()
return render(request, 'add_location.html', {'form': form})
```